# How can I make my Python program's executable file?

Tags: python

I want it to run anywhere directly.
For example, we build the c or c++ program and it generates a .exe file. Now we can take that .exe file and run it on any windows machine right?

The main problem I am facing is:
I have different packages like BeautifulSoup in my program which does not come pre-installed in ubuntu. Now when I run my program on my machine, it runs but not on other.
So is there any way I can make it directly run on any linux machine? It will be great if I can also run it on Windows too.

Comment: the simple way is to make your program look for those libraries in your current folder and if there not there, download them from somewhere (implementation with try catch)

Comment: Use Nuitika ( http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html ). Compile Python program to C++. Compile C++ to executable like you do with any other C++ program.

Comment: VirtualEnv. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: also there is this https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller I didn't use it so read the wiki

Comment: I have never used it but please check if http://www.py2exe.org/ would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current recommendations for packaging Python programs to run on machines that already have Python installed can be found [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/).

To run a Python program on a system that may or may not have Python installed, look into [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki), [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).